# OpenStackSDK create instance under specific project

Tags: python, openstack, openstacksdk

I'm trying to create instances using openstacksdk python api everything is ok but even when i use:

```
conn2 = conn.connect_as_project(proj.name)
server = conn2.create_server(......)
```

the server is being created under property of admin project, not the project mentioned in proj.name I even tried project.id but didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

Finally instead of:

```py
conn2 = conn.connect_as_project(project_id)
```

I used:

```py
conn2 = openstack.connection.Connection(
    region_name='RegionOne',
    auth=dict(
        auth_url='http://controller:5000/v3',
        username=u_name,
        password=password,
        project_id=project_id,
        user_domain_id='default'),
    compute_api_version='2',
    identity_interface='internal')
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I did this just fine...the only difference is that the project is a new project and I have to give credentials to the user I was using.

It was something like that:

```py
project = sconn.create_project(
    name=name, domain_id='default')
user_id = conn.current_user_id
user = conn.get_user(user_id)
roles = conn.list_roles()
for r in roles:
    conn.identity.assign_project_role_to_user(
        project.id, user.id, r.id
    )
# Make sure the roles are correctly assigned to the user before proceed
conn2 = self.conn.connect_as_project(project.name)
```

After that, anything created (servers, keypairs, networks, etc) is under the new project.